# How to create a logistic activation function in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

https://github.com/dnishimoto/python-deep-learning/blob/master/Deep%20Learning%20-%20blood%20donations.ipynb

The statement to solve:  We set 2 perceptron layers, one hidden layer with 3 neurons as a first guess
#and one output layer with 1 neuron, both layers having the logistic activation function

Can I use sigmoid as the logistic activation function

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

early_stopping_monitor=EarlyStopping(patience=3)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.05), loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])

scalar = MinMaxScaler()
scalar.fit(X)
X_scaled = scalar.transform(X)

model.fit(X_scaled, y,callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor],  epochs=500, verbose=False)

 y_pred=model.predict(X_scaled)
 buffer=y_pred.flatten()
 #print(buffer)
 yes=buffer[buffer>=.5]
 no=buffer[buffer<.5]
 print(len(yes))
 print(len(no))

 counts=[len(no),len(yes)]
 plt.bar(range(2),counts)
 plt.ylabel("Counts")
 plt.xlabel("Rejection/Success")

 plt.annotate(str(len(no)), xy=(0,len(no)))
 plt.annotate(str(len(yes)), xy=(1,len(yes)))
```

plt.show

Comment: The sigmoid activation function in Keras is the standard logistic function 1/(1+exp(-x)). https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/

Comment: No, I was responding to your question, "Can I use sigmoid ***as*** the logistic activation function," by saying that the sigmoid in Keras ***is*** the standard logistic function.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. You said that you are supposed to have “both layers having the logistic activation function” and you asked, “Can I use sigmoid as the logistic activation function?”, so I’m telling you that “Yes, you can use ‘sigmoid’ ***as*** the logistic activation function, because in Keras the ‘sigmoid’ activation ***is*** the standard logistic function.” (link to documentation in previous comment)